# Override value of Input Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with an input button for which I want to change the value:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-success">
```

CSS selector if it's needed:

```
#form > div.box-footer > div > div > input:nth-child(2)
```

Value is `Ajouter`, but I would like to have `Commander` displayed. I don't want to change the source code of my Laravel app so I'm looking for a solution. I would appreciate some tips & tricks here, since I'm stuck.

Comment: `$('#form > div.box-footer > div > div > input:nth-child(2)').val('Commander');` have you tried this?

Comment: what have you tried thus far?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee, got it, work fine, thanks a lot, cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can select the input and change its value after the dom is loaded

```js
$('input[value="Ajouter"]').val('Commander')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-success">
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in your jquery file.

```
 $('#form > div.box-footer > div > div > input:nth-child(2)').prop("value","Commander");
```